# Using StreamReader/StreamWriter in a class

Tags: c#, streamreader

Here is the code I'm using to read from a file:

```
string myPath = "file.txt";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myPath))
{
     while (!sr.EndOfStream)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
     }
     sr.Close();
}
```

If I place this code in Main() in the Program.cs file everything works as expected. However, I've created a custom class with a method to perform this exact code and I get red lines under **myPath** saying *"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream"*, and I get red lines under **sr.Close()** saying *"'StreamReader' does not contain a definition for 'Close' and no accessible extension method 'Close' accepting a first argument of type 'StreamReader' could be found"*.

For example, my class' method is something like this...

```
public void ReadFile() {
     string myPath = "file.txt";
     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myPath)) // Red lines under myPath
     {
          while (!sr.EndOfStream)
          {
               Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
          }
          sr.Close(); // Red lines under Close
     }
}
```

Both Program.cs and my custom class have **using System.IO;** at the top as well.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

The whole class looks like this...

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileReaderLibrary
{
     public class FileReader
     {
          public void ReadFile() {
              string myPath = "file.txt";
              using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myPath)) // Red lines under myPath
              {
                   while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                   {
                        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                   }
                   sr.Close(); // Red lines under Close
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: How did you name your custom class?

Comment: you can't use "using" inside a class

Comment: @yekanchi He means a method. See example.

Comment: The redline is under "myPath"?  You probably have a error earlier i the code.  Commend out the method an get rid of all the other errors and then see if you still get you error.

Comment: Can you include your custom Class definition ? as far as i can see the code you provided is correct and should compile.

Comment: You probably defined StreamReader yourself.  Right-click the name and click "Go To Definition".

Comment: I copied your class into a new VS project and it compiles perfectly. That leads me to believe that what you posted is not exactly what you have in your project. Specifically, I would look at typos where you used different cases in your variable names, etc.

Comment: @John - What I posted was copy/pasted. I just changed the file name.

When I paste that code into Main() in Program.cs it works perfectly. It's just giving me the error in the separate class file. Almost like it doesn't recognize StreamReader (or StreamWriter).

Comment: Is what you posted the entirety of the class file? Try this: Create a new clean class file and RETYPE  - do not copy/paste - the code from your existing class. Then, remove your original class from the project. I have seen times where hidden characters creep into a file and cause weird issues.